# SMB folders, upload a file results in .part files of 0bytes

Tags: debian, samba

I have a Debian 11 server with Nextcloud on it and an OpenMediaVault (OMV) server on which a Samba 4.13.13 share is configured.

The Samba server is used by all users on the network without any problem. However, when I connected smb on the Debian server (with users I use elsewhere so I know for sure I have all the correct permissions) to share a folder and make it available I had a lot of problems (the folder is mounted in fstab and not with the Nextcloud GUI, this is not a question about NC but about SMB).

What happens is that I can do `ls` inside the folder and see the files, I can do rm to remove them but I cannot in any way copy or upload files inside (except for ridiculously small files. e.g. if with vim I create a text file and write something in it it works, if I copy a png of few MB it doesn't work).
When I copy a file what happens is that the command stays on hold until I get an error (cp says "cp: failed to close '/mnt/path/filename': Host is down") and in the folder I find a file with a .part extension that weighs 0 bytes. At that point I can't even do `umount -f` to unmount the folder and all `ls`, `cd` or even auto-complete operations with the TAB inside the folder stop working or take a lot of time. The fstab line is this

```
//192.168.0.1/path/on/server/ /mnt/localpath/ cifs username=admin,password=adminpass,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noexec 0 0
```

I tried looking in the OVM logs but I couldn't find anything, I don't know if it's because I'm looking in the wrong place or because OVM doesn't log properly, I know there were some issues about how they decided to handle the logs but I'm not up to date on the issue